# How to convert qcow2 to file-system or archive file

Tags: linux, image, debian, extract, converters

before I start to write my problem, be not so hard to me, english is not my mother language.

My Debian10 on a dedicated Server get broken, but I have a qcow2 image. I copy the image to a other server and I installed Debian10 new.

But all my important files are on the image, so my question is, how to convert qcow2 to tar,zip etc. or to a directory, so I get my lost files.
I search a lot of time in the internet, but I can't find a solution.

All in one:
Can you give me a way to convert qcow2 images to archive files like zip,tar etc. or convert it in a normal file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `qcow2` image to raw file and mount it as a loop device (see `losetup`).

See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268460/how-to-mount-qcow2-image

Comment: Can this destroy other files from me

Comment: I get the following error:
`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nbd0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Comment: If you mount a `raw` copy of `qcow2`, your data won't be altered. If you mount `qcow2` image itself, mount it `read-only` to keep your data intact. 
The error suggests you have a specific filesystem on this image, you can specify it as `mount -t vfat` for example